# What is Difference between `msg.chat.id` and `msg.from.id` in Telegeram Bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

What is Difference between `msg.chat.id` and `msg.from.id` in Telegeram Bot? **Apparently, both are the same and Return user id.**

```
bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Hi', opts)
```

and

```
bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, 'Hi', opts)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

a **chatId** is a unique identifier for a chat, that can be either `private`, `group`, `supergroup` or `channel` whereas **userId** is a unique identifier for a user or bot only.

The only time the values can be the same is in a private chat.

Read more about Telegram types [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-types).

Comment: by the third line of your answer, do you mean two private chats can have the same value in some circumstances?

Comment: @ShahryarSaljoughi No, each chat is unique to itself there are no intersection